# How to connect to MSSQL Server with windows authentication and Force Encryption set to true

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I was connecting to Sql Server 2008 & 2008+ via Java program with

- Java 8
- Sql jdbc microsoft driver 4.1
- Connection string: `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://<Ip>;instance=MSSQLSERVER;domain=<domain>;IntegratedSecurity=true;ssl=request;", "administrator", "password");`

I was able to connect successfully.
However when I enabled Force encryption to true in the sql server via sql server configuration manager.

[image]
I started getting following error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ClientConnectionId:xxxx
```

FYI: 
I have already tried adding below parameters in connection string.

- ssl=request
- ssl=require
- encrypt=true
- trustServerCertificate=true
- Also I have tried upgrading the driver to 4.2 & mssql driver 7.0
- Tried jtds driver as well
- Point to be noted: I am able to connect to instance via ssms

EDIT 1

**- Another important point - It's happening only for windows authentication (enabled via IntegratedSecurity=true; in connection string).
So this case is happening only when Force encryption is set to true and we try to connect in windows authentication mode.**

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a newer driver (4.1 and 4.2 are pretty old, current latest is 7.0.0)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I have tried upgrading to latest mssql jdbc driver 7.0.0 as well. No luck.

Comment: Which Java 8 version are you using? Things changed in the SSL/TLS support during the Java 8 release cycle, maybe there is an incompatibility with the SQL Server 2008 SSL/TLS support.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel One more point. When I upgrade to latest 7.0.0 driver the exception error was different
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:Connection reset ClientConnectionId:xxx

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using 1.8.0_191 version

Comment: What happens if you start your application with `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`?

Comment: with TLSv1: same error                 
and with TLSv1.1, 1.2: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.".

Comment: Hmm, you may need to tweak some other security/encryption settings as well; but I'm a bit out of my depth here, and I don't think I'll be able to give more help.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel turned out that this problem occurs only when I am trying to connect to sql server in windows authentication mode with Force encryption set to true. Is it like both integratedsecurity=true and encrypted connection cannot go hand in hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Vivien @MarkRotteveel Thanks for your answers which gave me directions.

It turned out that sql server with version less then 11.0 were having troubles and various improvements were done as part of 11.0 version of sql server which rectified errors of windows authentication + encrypted connections connectivity.

[image]

So Sql server 2012 and above will support windows authentication with TLSv1.2, windows authentication along with encrypted connections seamlessly.
Now I am using

- Java 8
- Sql server driver 4.2
- Windows 10
- No extra parameters in connection string.

Just for reference: Found on Microsoft website.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your original question wether you have already done this, but if not, try setting both at the same time: `encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true`

Also, what do the SQL Server logs say?

Comment: Of course I have tried setting these both parameters simultaneously. But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mark Rotteveel has right.

You need to check your version of both Java **and** SQL Server 2008.
TLS 1.2 has been enable by default in Java 8 since the u122, and appear in SQL Server 2008 only in the service pack 4 (version 10.0.6547.0, `select @@VERSION;` for check it)
If you don't meet the requierment, you have to choose between update the server or downgrade your jdk.
Perhaps their is an option in the JDK to retrieve the behavior prior to the update 122, but if it's the case, I don't know it.

And, for information, the mssql-jdbc driver has stop the support of SQL Server 2008 after the version 6.2.

Comment: I am able to connect to Sql server 2017 with Java 8 with mssql-jdbc driver 6+ even with TLSv1.2 enabled.
This problem only happens when I enable encryption in Sql server.